# How to convert float to be represented as XE-Y for any float

Tags: python-3.x, printing, floating-point

Im parsing a file which contain lines of floats separated by space in the format of: +/-0.XXXE-8 after reading the floats and keeps them in a list it changes to +/-X.XXXE-9.

What I'm trying to do is to print the number as +/-0.XXXE-8 (the same format I read it) but with no luck.

A sample line from the input file is:

```
0.43578E-08  0.48992E-08  0.54452E-08  0.59816E-08  0.64918E-08  0.69577E-08
```

The output of printing the line after reading it:

```
4.357800e-09 4.899200e-09 5.445200e-09 5.981600e-09 6.491800e-09 6.957700e-09
```

Is there a way to transform any float number to be represented as 0.XXXE-8 no matter what the number is, for example:

```
x = 1.3E-9
print(func(x)) -> 0.13E-8
```

would appreciate some help

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should edit the question to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Maybe there might be some error in your code?

Comment: I tried searching for a conversation method but didnt find any, I don't think I have some error in the parsing code cause the numbers are the same the only difference is the way they are kept after parsing

Comment: you do realize the numbers are identical? numerically speaking? it is just a display issue? because floats get 1 digit before the `.` by default when printing?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes I do, but because the format is important because its going to be input to some other program(not written by me) I need to change it to start with 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already realized the numbers are identical numerically speaking.

So it is just a display issue that you can cirumvent by formatting them yourself:

```
data = [0.43578E-08, 0.48992E-08, 0.54452E-08, 0.59816E-08, 0.64918E-08, 0.69577E-08]

def format_float_weirdly(myfloat):
    """Formats a float to 0.xxxxxxxe-08 if it would be presened as x.xxxxxxe-09
    when normally formatted. If not, the normal format is outputted.""" 
    float_String = f"{myfloat:.8n}"
    if float_String[1] == "." and float_String.endswith("e-09"):
        float_String = "0." + float_String.replace(".","").replace("e-09","e-08")
    return float_String


d2 = [format_float_weirdly(f) for f in data]
print(data)
print(d2)
```

Output:

```
# printout of data
[4.3578e-09, 4.8992e-09, 5.4452e-09, 5.9816e-09, 6.4918e-09, 6.9577e-09]

['0.43578e-08', '0.48992e-08', '0.54452e-08', '0.59816e-08', '0.64918e-08', '0.69577e-08']
```

You can adapt this to fit "any" other representation by doing some math and string slicing on the "normal string representation". Afaik there is no builtin way to "format" a float like you want by [normal string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) means.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! would also appreciate an upvote